# Dask compute() on a collection that doesn't fit in memory

Tags: python, memory, dask

What's the alternative to `dask.compute()` if the collection doesn't fit in memory? Some sort of memory mapping?

I looked through this [documentation](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/manage-computation.html), but didn't see upon quick glance.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that calling `.compute()` often produces an in-memory object like a NumPy array or a Pandas DataFrame that *must* fit in memory.

Often this isn't a problem, because the output of many analyses tends to be small (like the data points that end up in a plot), or because the output is intentionally stored, as in the case of `df.to_parquet('...')`.  However sometimes you do want to trigger computation, but keep the data resident in distributed memory.  In this case people tend to use the `.persist()` method instead of `.compute()`.

See the [persist API documentation](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.persist) for more information.